# Canvas line continuously curve

Tags: javascript

I creating a continuously drawing curve line dynamically. Result like the image below. Should I apply `bezierCurveTo` when `lineLength` is exceed 50 ?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Curve Line</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="curve-line" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("curve-line");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      let lineLength = 0;
      let lineY = canvas.height / 2;

      // Update the line length and height every 100ms
      setInterval(() => {
        // Increase the line length by a random amount between 1 and 5
        lineLength += + 5;

         if(lineLength > 50)lineY -= 1;

        // Keep the line height within the canvas bounds
        if (lineY < 0) {
          lineY = 0;
        } else if (lineY > canvas.height) {
          lineY = canvas.height;
        }

        // Clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Start a new path
        ctx.beginPath();

        // Move the starting point to the left side of the canvas
        ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);

        // Draw a line to the right side of the canvas with the current length and height
        ctx.lineTo(lineLength, lineY);

        // Set the line color to red
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

        // Set the line width to 2 pixels
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;

        // Stroke the path
        ctx.stroke();
      }, 100);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `bezierCurveTo` to draw continuously curve line

Comment: @jyangca Hi, how to fit `bezierCurveTo` into the code ?